# How can i check if a string query condition is met

Tags: c#, oledbcommand

I have a file uploader that uploads excel files to a database in MySQL server. The file uploader is working fine and I also made a grid view that will show the history of all uploaded files in a section below.

Now I'm trying to develop some code that would enable the file uploader to check the database for when the uploaded file has duplicate rows and ask the user if he would like to replace the old record for the new one.

Note: the duplicates are not 100% equal. For example, in this situation, a duplicate will have the same id, year and month but different value. In other words, there can only be one id for a certain year and month despite the value.

Here is what I have so far. Marked as commentary the code where I'm not sure what to do in order to achieve what I mentioned.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String sID_VARIAVEL;
            int sANO;
            int sMES;
            int sCOD_DATA;
            String sINSTALACAO;
            String sVALOR;
            string path = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
            path = path.Replace(" ", "");
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Upload/") + path);
            String ExcelPath = Server.MapPath("~/Upload/") + path;
            OleDbConnection mycon = new OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = " + ExcelPath + "; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0; Persist Security Info = False");
            mycon.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Sheet1$]", mycon);
            OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                sID_VARIAVEL = dr[0].ToString();
                sANO = Convert.ToInt32(dr[1].ToString());
                sMES = Convert.ToInt32(dr[2].ToString());
                sCOD_DATA = Convert.ToInt32(dr[3].ToString());
                sINSTALACAO = dr[4].ToString();
                sVALOR = dr[5].ToString();
                savedata(sID_VARIAVEL, sANO, sMES, sCOD_DATA, sINSTALACAO, sVALOR);

                /*String query = "SELECT * FROM VALOR WHERE ID_VARIAVEL = '" + sID_VARIAVEL + "' AND ANO = '" + sANO + "' AND MES = '" + sMES + "' ";
                Boolean parsedquery;
                String myconn = "Data Source=agrsql004\\instance01; Initial Catalog=TrainingDB; User id=SQLLOCAL; Password=123456";
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myconn);
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
                command.CommandText = query;
                command.Connection = conn;
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                if ()
                {
                    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("????", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel);
                }*/
            }

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("File", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Size", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Type", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("YourDateField", typeof(DateTime));

            foreach (string strFile in Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Upload/")))
            {
                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(strFile);

                dt.Rows.Add(fi.Name, fi.Length, GetFileTypeByExtension(fi.Extension), fi.CreationTime);
            }

            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }


        private void savedata(String sID_VARIAVEL1, int sANO1, int sMES1, int sCOD_DATA1, String sINSTALACAO1, String sVALOR1)
        {
            String query = "insert into VALOR (ID_VARIAVEL, ANO, MES, COD_DATA, INSTALACAO, VALOR) values('" + sID_VARIAVEL1 + "','" + sANO1 + "','" + sMES1 + "','" + sCOD_DATA1 + "','" + sINSTALACAO1 + "','" + sVALOR1 + "')";
            String mycon = "Data Source=agrsql004\\instance01; Initial Catalog=TrainingDB; User id=SQLLOCAL; Password=123456";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(mycon);
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

Comment: It sounds like your SQL query needs to have a ````IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = @id) ```` and have conditional logic based on that.

Comment: And to add, you can return values from your SQL query that you look for.  So if it doesn't exist, you insert it.  If it does exist, return a specific value that you look for and then prompt a message to the user.  Look into @@ROWCOUNT: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: `if (reader.Read())`
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read

Comment: @Orwel I 'tried' that but ended up nowhere because I didn't know what to do afterward. It wasn't detecting any duplicates even tho there was one with the file I used to test it and ```result``` was always popping up even when there wasn't any duplicate. But well, I wasn't really sure what to do when I did that either and still don't :)

Comment: Also keep in mind that you will need to exit the reader and prompt a message for the user to respond to if you do find duplicates, so I wouldn't think using the reader is the best.  I'd do a for loop, and remember the iteration you were on so you pick up where you left depending on the users response.  EDIT: this is assuming you want the user to respond to a row-by-row basis.  If it's a flat out "replace all" then you'll still need to know the rows that need updated.

Comment: Your SQL query is also vulnerable to SQL injection.  I'd recommend using parameters instead.  https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp.  You can use ````cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue()````

Comment: @JohnPete22 I used ```cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue()``` in another grid view to update and add new rows to a database just like this ```sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_VARIAVEL", (GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtID_VARIAVEL") as TextBox).Text.Trim());``` but I used textboxes to insert or update the new data. How can I apply that to something that comes from an excel file that is being uploaded?

Comment: You need to get the collection of cells for the row you are in.  And then for each cell (you'll identify these by the cell name or index number - ID_VARIAVEL or 0) you'll grab the value.  Like I said before, I'd do a FOR LOOP so you know which row in the document you are in.  And if that row already exists, pop a message to the user.  Depending on the answer, you'll either update that row or continue with your loop.

Answer (score 1):

This is just an **alternative** way to see the data. I honestly don't like .xlx documents, so I tend to use .csv or .txt (tab or comma delimited).  Plus, we typically don't use NUGET packages in our software so those nice Excel converters aren't an option (they might be for you though).  You could alter this for an Excel document. I originally wrote this in VB, so had to convert it to C#.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

    private DataTable _dt;
    private Collection<int> _rowsNeedUpdated;

    public void TestFunction()
    {
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath("~/Files/ImportData_TabDelimited.txt"), Encoding.UTF8);
        bool isFirstLine = true;

        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            if (isFirstLine)
            {
                string[] headers = line.Split('\t');
                foreach (string header in headers)
                {
                    // dont want any whitespaces
                    _dt.Columns.Add(header.Replace(" ", ""));
                }

                isFirstLine = false;
                continue;
            }

            string[] items = line.Split('\t');
            DataRow row = _dt.NewRow();

            for (int i = 0; i < _dt.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                row[_dt.Columns[i].ColumnName] = items[i];
            }

            _dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        // these are just methods of getting specific row data (similar to a SQL WHERE clause)
        DataRow[] rows = _dt.Select("ID_VARIAVEL = '5'");
        DataRow[] rows2 = _dt.Select(String.Format("ID_VARIAVEL LIKE '%{0}%' AND ANO = '1'", "formattedString"));




        for (int i = 0; i < _dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            // get each datarow item
            // example
            string id = (string)_dt.Rows[i]["columnName"];

            // execute SQL query and check the return value based on my previous comments
            // if it needs to be updated, capture the row to update later
            _rowsNeedUpdated.Add(i);
        }

    }
```